# How to open a terminal with root privilege from a php based web application

Tags: command-line, php

I have a web application in lampp ubuntu machine I need to open a terminal to perform some operations can somebody help me with this

Thanks in advance

Comment: This looks like a [dangerous idea](https://plus.google.com/photos/photo/106378848135270560799/6392191587737574962?icm=false). What do you really need to do?

Comment: I am doing a project on sentiment analysis and using Rscript for that and have created a web application for the user end so admin has the authority to perform sentiment analysis and return results to user.. from admin page I needed to open a terminal is it possible?

Comment: No, wrong approach. You need to store the data from the web site into a text file on the server and can then use a directory watcher on the server to perform actions on that data, create a new text file with the results and have the webpage pick up this new data.

Comment: @Rinzwind You should have added that as an answer: 5 upvotes already for your comment...  :)

Comment: @Fabby you'd better upvote me :=)

Answer (score 2):

No, that is the wrong approach. I would roughly do it like this:

- Store the data from the web site on the server in a database, or as a text file.
- Use a script (a service, or a directory watcher in `/etc/crontab`) on the server where you fill a file in the database or create a text file with the data from this text file
- have the webpage pick up this new data after you manipulated the data to get the desired results.

The database approach is better but a bit more work. A well designed database forces you to validate the data and makes manipulation of the data easy. You can use a "procedure" in MySQL to manipulate the data. Dumping a text file is easier but validating and manipulating a text file can be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Rinzwind's approach is this:

1. Write a script that wraps the privileged command, e. g.,

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   set -eu
   input="$1"
   output="$2"
   exec /path/to/data-analysis-program [OPTIONS...] "$input" "$output"
   ```

   Save it as, say, `/other/path/to-data-analysis-wrapper.sh` and make it executable:

   ```
   chmod +x /other/path/to-data-analysis-wrapper.sh
   ```

   Test that the wrapper script does what you want with:

   ```
   sudo /other/path/to-data-analysis-wrapper.sh <INPUT-FILE> <OUTPUT-FILE>
   ```
2. Transfer the ownership of the file to a user that makes it unwriteable to the user owning the web server process, e. g. `root`:

   ```
   sudo chown root /other/path/to-data-analysis-wrapper.sh
   ```
3. Configure `sudoers` to allow the execution of the script by the user who owns the web server process with elevated privileges. See [How do I run specific sudo commands without a password?](/q/159007/175814) for how to do that in general and use the following rule (or tweak it to your liking):

   ```
   www-data ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /other/path/to-data-analysis-wrapper.sh *
   ```
4. You can now execute `sudo /other/path/to-data-analysis-wrapper.sh <INPUT-FILE> <OUTPUT-FILE>` from CGI scripts running on behalf of the web server.

An even better approach is to set up your data analysis processes in a way that doesn't require super-user privileges. If this is only about number crunching and not about privileged system or hardware access then there a should be a relatively simple way. Please open a new question and describe the situation more in-depth if you want to go down that road.